# How to measure context switching and duration of thread running

Tags: multithreading, cpu-usage, metrics, perf

As we know, Linux system has a functionality to switch contexts of threads to archive concurrency. I need to measure some metrics to have them visualized.
What metrics I need:

1. A CPU time when a thread is loaded to a CPU to run
2. A CPU time when a thread is offloaded from a CPU
3. A CPU core

Example:
I have a process with 2 threads (main and additional)

Metrics:

| PID | TID | Time | Event | CPU core |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 85.0234 | CPU takes on this thread | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 85.1102 | CPU takes off this thread | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 85.1201 | CPU takes on this thread | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 85.1409 | CPU takes off this thread | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 86.0192 | CPU takes on this thread | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 86.1122 | CPU takes off this thread | 2 |
| 1 | 2 | 86.2012 | CPU takes on this thread | 3 |
| 1 | 2 | 86.2513 | CPU takes off this thread | 3 |

Having this metrics I can calculate how much time it took for first Thread(TID 1) to be performed on each iteration. For example, the first iteration is **0.0868** (85.1102 - 85.0234)

Do you know any tools which help me with that? Could you provide some examples to get it started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at 'perf sched'

And for reporting you could check out 'perf sched timehist' and 'perf sched latency'.

For more information see:
https://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2017-03-16/perf-sched.html